# Primeiramente, segundamente, ... até quanto?

Tags: advérbios

Um exemplo do uso da expressão 'primeiramente' seria quando queremos escrever 'em primeiro lugar'. Do mesmo modo, suponho que possamos também usar a expressão segundamente, terceiramente, e assim sucessivamente.

Estarei certo nesta minha suposição?

E levando o meu raciocínio mais além, até que posição/número poderemos criar uma palavra semelhante a '# +mente'?

Comment: Eu diria que parece um uso em inglés.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como um falante nativo da língua portuguesa, **nunca ouvi "segundamente", "terceiramente" ou "quartamente", a não ser em comédias.**  É verdade que essas formas, em contexto, seriam compreendidas.  No entanto **não são idiomáticas e soariam um tanto ridículas**.

Eu geralmente uso "em primeiro lugar". "Primeiramente", por ser menos usada, deixo para situações mais formais quando quero dar ênfase àquela posição. E, certamente, nunca uso as formas "segundamente", "terceiramente", "quartamente", etc.

Comment: Exatamente. Telling it like it is. So unusual around here (including other sites).

Comment: In Brazil you will hear segundamente and tarceiramente. The thing is, most memories I recall now, from people saying these words, were in a context where they were trying to sound funny or silly. But I am sure I have also heard people saying it seriously.

Comment: @Delta  "O Bem Amado" would say "segundamente" and "terceiramente".

Answer (score 2):

Na aula de jornalismo, uma vez um colega fez essa mesma pergunta ao professor. Ele explicou que é melhor evitar a construção `Primeiramente`, pois seu uso implica que haveria um `Segundamente`, `Terceiramente` etc., gerando uma sequência esquisita e pouco usual ao leitor/interlocutor. Além disso, a partir de `Quartamente`, o vocábulo sequer consta no dicionário.

Ao invés das opções acima, é preferível usar as formas mais simples, diretas e elegantes `Primeiro`, `Segundo`, `Terceiro` etc., até o ponto que o autor desejar, sem prejuízo à mensagem transmitida.

Comment: Por vezes, gostaria que a língua Portuguesa fosse mais elástica/plástica e suportasse alguma iniciativa e criatividade do escritor.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Ela é! A questão é que, quando existe uma forma mais simples e certamente correta, escrever de uma forma mais incomum pode soar estranho ao leitor. No âmbito criativo, nada de impede de escrever da forma que quiser, não é ilegal fugir da norma e pessoas fazem isso o tempo inteiro. A dúvida que fica é se o seu público alvo irá entender ou interpretar sua obra da forma desejada. Eu também fico curioso para saber exemplos dessa elasticidade em outras línguas que não exista no português.

Answer (score 1):

É claro que "primeiramente" está correto.
E também não há problema algum com "segundamente".
https://sualingua.com.br/primeiramente/

Comment: Olá, boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que sua resposta é na verdade um comentário, pois não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação o bastante](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), você poderá deixar comentários em postagens.